# "on my mac" calendar option missing from New Calendar menu

Tags: macos, icloud, calendar

I recently did a clean install of Mountain Lion (upgrading from Lion). Exported my calendars to a "Calendar Archive" on Lion and then imported them on Mountain Lion.

Maybe I broke something, but I don't see a way to add new calendars "on my mac". The only option i have in File | New Calendar is "iCloud" (which is not what i want). Is there a preference I'm missing somewhere?

A possibly related problem: syncing with iCloud seems to be broken. I get a triangle alert icon to show there has been a problem (but there is no clue what the problem is). I spent and hour on Google hunting but couldn't find a place to look for logged error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you'll have to:

1. **Disable** iCloud by going to **Calendar > Preferences > Accounts**. It seems important just to disable iCloud from Calendar's preferences, not completely sign out of it from within *System Preferences*.
2. Create a new calendar which name does not conflicts with any calendars you've already got in your iCloud.
3. Enable your iCloud account.

This will make the new calendar, under *On My Mac* to remain.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to open the Automator app, Once inside of it, search for add calendar  and add it to the right canvas aria. Then name the calendar anything and set it to create “on my mac”. Click the play button at the top of the window. Go back to calendar and the “on my mac” should  be back there again. As long as you  have more than zero calendar at a time under on my mac , it should stay there.